# HTML get the value of an image field and use that value as a src for an image field

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a HTML input field like this

```
<input type="text" id="Bild"/>
```

I want to get the value of the input field and store it in a String in my JSP page, something like this

```
<%
String theString= <input type="text" id="Bild"/>
%>
```

After that I want to use the string to as a source for my image field, like this

```
<img src= <%= theString %> >
```

I have no clue how to do this, and I've been staring at the screen for two hours not getting my head straight. How can I get the value of the input field to use for my image source?

I'm new to JavaScript so if I have to use this, please be very descriptive. Thanks.

Comment: If you're cool with using jQjuery you could simply grab the value of the text field using http://api.jquery.com/val/ then place that value into the image src field.

Comment: Yes, sure that sounds very good. But how do I do this? As I said, I'm a complete beginner with JavaScripts and Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes a pre-existing image's `src` when the `byt` button is clicked.

```
function bytUtBilden() {
    // select <input id="Bild"/>
    var bildenFalt = document.getElementById('Bild');

    // select <img id="bilden"/>
    var bilden = document.getElementById('bilden');

    bilden.src = bildenFalt.value;
}

function begynna() {
    // select element with id="byt"; when clicked, run bytUtBilden
    document.getElementById('byt').addEventListener('click',bytUtBilden,false);
}

// when DOM is loaded, run begynna()
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',begynna,false);
```

**Edit:** Changed it so that it updates when the button is clicked. Also `bytUtBilden()` can be run from anywhere and it will do the same thing.

Comment: Alright, I believe I can make sense out of this. How do I implement this in my .JSP page? Inside a <script> tag?

Comment: Yeah, just put `<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` in `<head/>`.

Comment: Okay, I've added my script to my JSP page and changed my field ID and img ID as you instructed me. What's the next step? How do I call this script to run?

Comment: Okay I've realized a problem:
My input field is not "populated" when the document loads. It gets populated when I click on a table row (using another javascript..) will this cause a problem with above code?

Comment: I don't foresee it having a problem. I don't know that it will fire the `change` event that's on the field, but you can attach `byUtBilden` to any field. Just change `evt.target` to `document.getElementById('Bild')` to make it read from that field instead of whatever fires it.

Comment: Also a demo with sample image URL. http://jsfiddle.net/3WCUy/ Just put in a URL then tab/click away from the field.

Comment: With the changes you've made (and some of my own modifications with the url) I got this to work for a button with id="byt". Now to get this to run as I intended, I'd like to do the same for a <tr> in a <table>. Initially I thought that giving the <tr> an id="byt" would do it, but it didn't turn out the same as for the button. My <tr> looks like this: 
<tr id="byt" onClick="javascript:showRow(this);">, it already has an onclick. Does this cause problems with adding another listener to the <tr>? I really appriciate your help here. This have taken up my whole day.

Comment: Not a problem! In `begynna()` you can add this and you won't need `onClick`: `document.getElementById('byt').addEventListener('click',showRow,false);` With event listeners you can add multiple actions to the same event.

Comment: that wont work since showRow takes a row as a parameter

Comment: Change the parameter in `showRow` to `e` and reference `e.target` where you need the row instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. But anyway, I think I'll go with using the button. It does the work for me. Thank you very much for this help.

Comment: Sure thing. When you add an EventListener (a function that fires on an event), it implicitly passes a variable to that function with information about the event. The `target` property points to the object firing the event.

Comment: Ah.. I have a hard time processing any more information today haha. I'll have a look tomorrow. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = $('Bild').val();
$('#imgid').attr('src',path);
```

Comment: any explanation you may want to give? I mean, I understand, but we cannot be sure the OP does too...

Comment: this is chinese to me

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to be going through a middle-man? Just grab the value with a direct DOM query as long as you know that the text field does already contain a value:

`document.getElementById('Bild').value`

In this example I used a button as the action, but you don't need that for the value to be query-able

http://jsfiddle.net/Py2E2/

Comment: I tried this, but with an onclick on a <tr> like this:
<tr onclick="showImage();"> but it doesn't work..

Comment: Hmmm the onclick listener should work for `<tr>` elements... in this example clicking on the table row does the same as clicking the submit button

http://jsfiddle.net/MCgLh/